# Remote Router Access For Linksys WRT54GL

Tags: router, remote

I just set up a wireless network at home using a Linksys WRT54GL. All was fine except that I can still access 192.168.1.1, the configuration setup page of the router, within the local wireless after I disabled "Remote  Management". I think if remote access is indeed disabled, one can access my router setup page only by using a cable connecting from his computer to the router. Is this true or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Remote Management is disabled by default and when enabled, it allows web access through the WAN port (basically the internet) on port 8080 (again default).  LAN access - both wired and wireless - is unaffected by this.

[WRT54GL User Guide](http://downloads.linksysbycisco.com/downloads/userguide/WRT54GL_V11_UG_C-Web.pdf), pp. 19:

> **Remote  Management** To  access  the  Router  remotely,  from outside the
>   network, select **Enable**.
>
> **Management Port** Enter  the  port  number  that will  be  open to outside
>   access. You will need to enter the
>   Router’s  password when accessing the
>   Router this way, as usual.
>
> **Use https** To require the use of HTTPS for remote access,  select this
>   feature.

Comment: Thank you! Did you say Wireless LAN and Wired LAN are both unaffected whether Remote Management is disabled? I think Wireless LAN will not be allowed if Remote Management is disabled.

Comment: "Remote" only applies to the physical connection to the WAN port in this case.  Wireless will still work as long as `Wireless Network Mode` is not `Disabled`, http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT54GL/4.30.0/Wireless.htm.

Answer (score 3):

Hyperslug's right, "Remote Access" here only covers the WAN side of the router.  Anything LAN or WLAN is "local access".

There is a separate option to cut off wireless access to the router's config. According to the same page of the [User Guide](http://downloads.linksysbycisco.com/downloads/userguide/WRT54GL%5FV11%5FUG%5FC-Web.pdf) (p.19) that hyperslug posted, on the Administration > Management config page, these two options can secure the local wireless access to the router config:

> **Access Server** HTTP (HyperText Transport Protocol) is
>   the communications protocol used to connect to servers
>   on the World Wide Web. HTTPS uses SSL (Secured Socket
>   Layer) to encrypt data transmitted for higher security.
>   Select HTTP or HTTPS. The default selection is HTTP.
>
> **Wireless Access Web** If you are using the Router in
>   a public domain where you are giving wireless access
>   to your guests, you can disable wireless access to the
>   Router’s web-based utility. You will only be able to access
>   the web-based utility via a wired connection if you disable
>   the setting. Keep the default, Enable, to enable wireless
>   access to the Router’s web-based utility, or select Disable
>   to disable wireless access to the utility.

If wireless access to your router's administration pages is a concern for you, you should change the first option to **HTTPS** (encrypt local access, for protected wireless access -- note this is not the same as the "Use https" option in the Remote Management section), or switch the second option to **Disable** (for no wireless access at all).