# Cannot access router outside of network

Tags: router, networking, ip-address

My router's ip cannot be accessed using my phone. It just says server not found.

Comment: You're going to have to work harder than that to get a good answer. How are you accessing it via your phone? What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: you should state what router you are using

Comment: smartphone questions are offtopic here unless in regards to syncing with a computer.  you might have better luck with http://forceclose.com/, http://slidetoask.com/, or another site on this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Answer (score 0):

No idea what router you use, but check out this:

[Remote Router Access For Linksys WRT54GL](https://superuser.com/questions/47095/remote-router-access-for-linksys-wrt54gl)

Are you trying to access something like - 192.168.1.1?  If so you won't be able to, that's a private IP to your home network.  You'll want to use a public IP that your router uses and you'll want to ensure that in the router settings remote login is enabled.